# Have to re-run the application to show the saved files after it is being saved

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

This application does not show the saved files after it is being saved in the list of save files. It has to be re-run every time you've added a file. 
[This](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=bafa39a62a57009c&sc=documents&id=BAFA39A62A57009C%21537#) is the source code for the application

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of navigating through the back stack after you add the file, use the Navigation service to return to the main page. When you go through the back stack, it just reloads the page in its prior state. Navigating to a new instance of the page would (should) cause the newly-added file to show.

Comment: something like this?  `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: Yes, just like that. (Sorry, I went to bed. :-) )